# HTTP & HTTP WCF Services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Can I have a WCF Service Project that has both HTTP (basic http binding) and HTTPS (basic http binding) bindings?  For example, I would have:

https://localhost:44303/ServiceA.svc
http://localhost:12345/ServiceB.svc

Would there be any benefit to putting them into separate service projects (and separate sites when we deploy the app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have HTTP binding, you don't need to change code to add HTTPS binding. This is a big advantage of WCF. Instead of adding a separate site, you just add a new endpoint to the configuration file.

Below is an example of configuration with both HTTP and HTTPS.
You can see that there two named bindings: notSecureBinding and secureBinding, which correspond to HTTP and HTTPS.

```
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="notSecureBinding"
               maxBufferSize="2147483647"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
      <binding name="secureBinding"
               maxBufferSize="2147483647"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="StandardServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="StandardServiceBehavior"
             name="ServiceName">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="notSecureBinding"
                contract="Namespace.IService"/>
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="secureBinding"
                contract="Namespace.IService"/>
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
```

Comment: @user472292 - do you host at IIS? Did you create SSL certificate? Did you bind certificate to the port?

Comment: If you need to be able to retrieve metadata via https endpoint you need to add `httpsGetEnabled="true"` to `serviceMetadata` element. Also you need to add one more mex endpoint.

Comment: @user472292 - the config that I show is from my production project and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted this and when I try to consume my secure service I get the following error:

```
 The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://localhost:44304/ExternalOrderProcessing.svc'. There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost:44304/ExternalOrderProcessing.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

When I try to consume my unsecure service I get the following error:

```
 The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:5000/LegacyOrderProcessing.svc'. Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:5000/LegacyOrderProcessing.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.. If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I am running this in IIS Express.  I have setup the project to allow SSL.  My config is as follows:

```
<services>
  <service name="ExternalOrderProcessing" behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingSecure" contract="IExternalOrderProcessing" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
  <service name="LegacyOrderProcessing" behaviorConfiguration="UnsecureBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" contract="ILegacyOrderProcessing" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SecureBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl=""/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="UnsecureBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>

  <basicHttpBinding>
    <!-- Used by external order processing service -->
    <binding name="BasicHttpBindingSecure"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            receiveTimeout="00:05:00"
            sendTimeout="00:05:00"
            openTimeout="00:05:00"
            closeTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"  />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <!-- Used to create binding to internal order processing service -->
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            receiveTimeout="00:05:00"
            sendTimeout="00:05:00"
            openTimeout="00:05:00"
            closeTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

</bindings>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

If I put the services into two separate projects, it works.  When I do that, I omit the services section in the config and remove the name="BasicHttpBindingSecure" and name="SecureBehavior".